# prevent date-object from updating its timezone on system's timezone change, behavior not consistent between browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Is there a way to prevent javascript's date-objects from updating its timezone, during system's timezone change?

when updating systems timezone, browser updates all instance of the date-object to newtimezone.

```
os: windows 10
browser: opera,
```

[image: browser console opera]

but the same behavior does not happen in Firefox.

```
os: windows 10
browser: firefox,
```

[image: browser console firefox]

Comment: The effective ISO time should be the same no?

Comment: @charlietfl yea, date.toISOString() is the same before and after.

Comment: So is there an actual problem or just a perceived one? Dates can certainly be confusing and complex

Comment: date objects initiated before timezone update must be of the same timezone?

Comment: Don't think it actually matters. The output string you see is a toString() type representation. The ISO value before and after is still the same

Comment: If thats the case, date.getHours() should not change right? "The getHours() method returns the hour for the specified date, according to local time". The value is different in chromium but same in firefox? so I have to somehow calculate the previous timezoneoffset based on toISOString(), after detecting the timezonechange?

Comment: I believe so. I guess what your issue might be is changing timezones in OS after date object is created may have different implementations of whether the timezone is evaluated every time you call  method on that object or if the timezone is stored in the object when it gets created. I definitely don't know about that or even know how you could manage it if it doesn't get evaluated each time a method is run